# get around allow_url_include=0 error

Tags: php

I am trying to include a file from a url, however I get the following error thrown up.

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/diningtime/testsite/salims/index1.php on line 58

Warning: include(http://localhost/diningtime/templates/100/index.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/diningtime/testsite/salims/index1.php on line 58

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://localhost/diningtime/templates/100/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/diningtime/testsite/salims/index1.php on line 58
Test
```

Just wondering if there is anyway around this?

My PHP include code is

```
<?php include "$location/index.php"; ?>
```

I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Why do you want to `include` a file from the same server through an HTTP request instead of through a local file path? Do you have a *need* to make an HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, when the site is live it will be pulling it from another server so I need to test the concept.

Comment: Assuming this is a remote file and not as deceze points out just a wrongly included local file... are you asking how to enable it? `ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);` or edit you php.ini file.

Comment: This might open the door to remote-file-inclusion attacks: https://www.incapsula.com/web-application-security/rfi-remote-file-inclusion.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're using a full URL as you include path, which tells PHP to attempt to do an HTTP request to fetch that file. This is **NOT** how you do this. Unless that `...100/index.php` outputs PHP code, you are going to get some HTML or whatever as the include result, NOT the php code in the file. Remember - you're fetching via URL, which means it's an HTTP request, which means the webserver will EXECUTE that script and deliver its output, not simply serve up its source code.

There's no way for the webserver to tell that the HTTP request for that script is an include call from another PHP script on the same server. It could just as easily be a request for that script from some hacker hiding in Russia wanting to steal your source code. Do you want your source code visible to the world like this?

For local files, you should never use a full-blown url. it's hideously inefficient, and will no do what you want. why not simply have

```
include('/path/to/templates/100/index.php');
```

instead, which will be a local file-only request, with no HTTP stage included?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, basically when the site is live I need to pull the source code from a generic file its basically so somebody can select from a range of templates for there sites. whats the best way of doing this if I can include a file via HTTP. I appreciate your help...

Comment: allowing includes via url is horribly bad. if you allow the user to directly specify a file to include, you're essentially allowing them to load ANY code, from ANYwhere, and your server will happily flush itself down the toilet. Rethink your design...

Comment: Hi this explains me the logic. But one doubt user is on the browser side how come he can able to include a file. Thanks @MarcB

Comment: @sun: there's plenty of horribly bad php scripts floating around that have things like `include($_GET['page'])`, where the site's coder expected people would only ever have `http://example.com?page=home.php` for urls, and never expected (or thought) someone would try `http://example.com?page=../../../../../etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue.

Considering 'Marc B's' post, it is clear that using absolute URLs is not a great idea, even if it is possible by editing the php.ini as 'ficuscr' states.  I'm not sure this workaround will work for your specific situation as it still requires adjustments to each page depending on where it is in your folder structure, but it does makes things simpler if, like me, you have a lot of includes in your website.

```
<?php $root="../";?>
<?php include($root . 'folder-A/file_to_be_included_1.php');?>
<?php include($root . 'folder-A/file_to_be_included_2.php');?>
<?php include($root . 'folder-B/file_to_be_included_3.php');?>
<?php include($root . 'folder-B/file_to_be_included_4.php');?>
<?php include($root . 'folder-B/sub-folder/file_to_be_included_5.php');?>
```

For me, this means if I move a page to another location in the folder structure, for example in a sub-folder of its current location, all I need to do is amend `<?php $root="../";?>` to become `<?php $root="../../";?>` for example