# Storing the contents of an external php stylesheet in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a php file that's being used as a dynamic stylesheet. So its a very large file with css/values generated by php. Here's an example.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>
.top {
    top: <?= $topValue ?>px;
}
More css...
```

On a separate file, i'm trying to get the generated content from the php file and store it on the page somewhere so I can get it later with javascript. So the method i'm trying is storing the contents in a hidden input. Like so.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("FILE_URL.php");
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-css" value="<?= $file ?>" />
```

However, when I do this, the value contains the raw php from the file and its also commenting out the opening/closing php tags. So for instance, its doing things like '< !--?php' instead of "< ?php" and "?-->" instead of "?>". This messes up the general html on the page and doesn't store the value correctly in the input.

So I ask you, how can I fix the current situation or better store the contents of the stylesheet on the page so I can later grab it and use it with javascript?

**EDIT:** There may also be an issue with quotes in the generated css causing issues. I'm not sure how to address this issue either.

**EDIT:** This is how it should be stored if everything worked perfectly.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-css" value="
.top {
top: 54px;
}
" />
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Output buffer would be one keyword, if you don’t want to change your script. (Although then the header it sends might still be problematic.) And please specify what _problem_ you are actually trying to solve here … because it sounds a lot like you might be barking up the wrong tree here already with your current approach.

Comment: what is use case for storing this css in an input ?

Comment: The approach: Trying to get the contents from the dynamic stylesheet in any way possible. The problem: The contents aren't being stored correctly in the current approach. Why im doing this: I need the generated css because im going to then use the css with a text editor plugin http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about. So I need to be able to grab the contents with javascript.

Comment: get the data using ajax

Comment: I've tried that. But then I get a cross-origin request issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the file_get_contents() function for this purpose - it simply gets the file contents (i.e. it won't run PHP on that file first).

Instead, as user574632 suggests, you must use `include` and so your code would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-css" value="<?php include 'FILE_URL.php'; ?>" />
```

Hopefully that solves your problem.

(Another quick note: Given your main file is HTML not CSS, you will probably need to declare that content header again after the input like this:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

)

Comment: allow_url_include is disabled on the server that this code will be running on and I can't change that. I don't know if this solution will work.

Comment: You can override that server setting with `ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);`. If you're still having issues due to the server, you might like to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277460/get-around-allow-url-include-0-error#

Comment: Hey, hopefully you're still here. The issue actually doesn't have to do with allow_url_include. The issue now is that the page is changing to content-type text/css and I can't change it back to text/html. In your example above, you explained that I would need to set the header to text/html, but where exactly do I put that? I've tried placing the line of code in several places, but the file continues to switch to text/css.

Comment: If re-declaring it isn't working, you'll need to add a catch to the original script to not add the header if it is run indirectly - i.e. setup a variable `$included = 1;` for example and check if this isn't set before declaring content type as `text/css`.
Example code:
`<?php if(!isset($included)) { header("Content-Type: text/css"); } ?>`
[For the css file]
`<?php $included = 1; ?>`
[For the HTML file]